# Why is this simple mesh stretching

Tags: mesh, uv

I don't understand the logic about this stretch, what i'm doing wrong 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try pressing numpad 5 to toggle orthographic and perspective modes. I think your mesh may be fine. Unless you're referring to flaws in the UV map?

Comment: Probably those faces aren't planar hence appear slightly stretched when unfolded on UV map

Comment: @Mr Zak the same part but on the other side, its a guitar neck, has no stretching. I even tried marking the sean of every face and they have stretching its weird

Comment: Is the scale of the mesh all 1?